# How do I do a `CREATE INDEX` with Percona's `pt-online-schema-change` tool?

Tags: mysql, sql, percona

How do I do a `CREATE INDEX` with Percona's `pt-online-schema-change` tool? I want to do something like:

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_name ON table_name (col_1, col_2, ...) USING BTREE`

According to the [documentation](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-online-schema-change.html), I must use the `--alter` argument and then the appropriate `ALTER TABLE` statement, minus the preceding `ALTER TABLE table_name` phrase. However, `CREATE INDEX` does not start with `ALTER TABLE`, and the table name is embedded inside the `CREATE INDEX` statement. So how can I move forward?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) for MySQL `CREATE INDEX`:

> CREATE INDEX is mapped to an ALTER TABLE statement to create indexes.

Thus, you can convert my example to the SQL statement:

`ALTER TABLE table_name ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_name (col_1, col_2, ...) USING BTREE`

Resulting in the Percona schema modification statement:

`ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_name (col_1, col_2, ...) USING BTREE`

Answer (score 6):

I use this one) 
pt-online-schema-change --alter 'add index ix_cdate (cdate)' D=database_name,t=table_name --dry-run --critical-load Threads_running=110

Comment: this helped with my syntax error while adding index